# PHP include not working (3rd statement)

Tags: php

I have some code and I don't know why the 3rd include statement is not working.  I've tried changing the order and it's still the 3rd that never work.

```
$filename = $includes_url . "php/LeagueFunctions2010.php";
if(file_exists($filename)) {
    echo $filename . " found <br />";
    include_once($filename);
    echo $filename . ' included <br />';
} else {
    echo "Filename: " . $filename . "<br />";
    exit ("Missing file.");
}

$filename = $includes_url . "php/GetUserInfo.php";
if(file_exists($filename)) {
    echo $filename . " found <br />";
    include_once($filename);
    echo $filename . ' included <br />';
} else {
    exit ("Missing file. Filename:" . $filename);
}

$filename = $includes_url . "php/league_functions.php";
if(file_exists($filename)) {
    echo $filename . " found <br />";
    include_once($filename);
    echo $filename . ' included <br />';
} else {
    exit ("Missing file. Filename:" . $filename);
}
```

The result is:

> /home1/chasiv/public_html/League/_includes/php/LeagueFunctions2010.php
>   included 
>   /home1/chasiv/public_html/League/_includes/php/GetUserInfo.php
>   included

I've used multiple includes on tons of pages but for some reason this is failing.

Comment: Some error would help. Try to use `include_once()` instead of `include()`.

Comment: if(file_exists($filename) is failing.  Maybe the file doesn't exist.  Are you sure it's spelled exactly like that?  I ask because considering the scheme used for the others, it should be spelled "LeagueFunctions.php"

Comment: Probably a syntax error in league_functions.php. Check your error log.

Comment: As I mentioned, I've changed the includes around and it does not matter which is the 3rd one.  So it's not an issue with the functions.  I've also tried include, include_one and require to no avail.

Comment: I've also included     echo $filename . " found <br />"; in front of each call and all 3 files are found.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. You're not displaying errors with just `error_reporting(E_ALL);` unless you've got logs.

Comment: plus, try adding numbers to `$filename`, you've got all the same variables. I.e.: `$filename1` etc. might be a conflict somewhere.

Comment: Fred, I've tried that as well.  ($filename, $filename1, $filename2).  I've also tried unset($filename) after each grouping.

Comment: well, you have mixed letter case for `LeagueFunctions2010.php` and `GetUserInfo.php` but not for `league_functions.php`. If you're on Unix/Linux, `league_functions.php` is not the same as `League_Functions.php` should that be the case. That's all I can think of at this point. So, error reporting didn't throw anything, even after adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't do `require($_GET['file']);`

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue.  There were duplicate function names in league_functions & LeagueFunctions2010.php.   That is the reason changing the order did not matter.  Thanks to everyone for the suggestions.

Comment: I take it that error reporting spat out "cannot redeclare function..."?